# How to send/return data/value from CI_Controller to AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, web

As the title, i want to CI_Controller return value/data back to AJAX which give request before.

**The_Controller.php**

```
class The_Controller extends CI_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function postSomething()
    {
        $isHungry = true;
        if(isHunry){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

}

**AJAX**

$(document).ready(function() 
        {

```
        $('#form').on('submit', function (e)
        {
            e.preventDefault(); // prevent page reload
            $.ajax ({
                type : 'POST', // hide URL
                url : '/index.php/The_Controller/postSomething',
                data : $('#form').serialize (),
                success : function (data)
                {
                    if(data == true)
                    {
                        alert ('He is hungry');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert ('He is not hungry');
                    }       
                }
                , error: function(xhr, status, error)
                {
                    alert(status+" "+error);
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
            return true;
        });
    });
```

**The Problem :**

The AJAX code above always get FALSE for variable **data**. It's not get return value from postSomething function inside CI_Controller.

**The Question :**

I want to if(data == true) result alert ('He is hungry');. But cause data not fill by return value of postSomething function inside CI_Controller so it always false. **How to get return value/data from CI_Controller to AJAX?**

Thank you

Comment: You have to print like echo $isHungry; OR echo json_encode($isHungry); Also you may add dataType: json in ajax call for json data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change your code a little bit. no need to return data, just `echo true` or `echo false` from your controller. Hope you will get your desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in the PHP code

```
    if(isHunry){
```

should be

```
    if($isHungry){
```

Also, returning data to an AJAX request, you really should be sending the correct content type in the header. Ex.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

And `print` or `echo` the data, not `return` it, as well as `json_encode` it:

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

So your `postSomething` php function should look something like this:

```
$isHungry = true;
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($isHungry);
```